# Is built in ASP.NET Membership Hashing good enough?

Tags: asp.net, security, hash, membership

I'm just wondering if the built in Hashing in the ASP.Net membership good password security, or if there is more that I should do to protect my passwords?  If so, what should I look into for a higher level of security?

Comment: Good enough for what? Military-grade secrets or the Towns Women Guild's extranet?

Comment: haha.. good point.  Basically it's a basic web app. No military secrets, or anything mission critical.  I just want to make sure it's secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hashing method with salt is pretty good. However how good the security is also depends a bit on how secure your application has to be.

Probably not good enough for securing bank accounts, hangar 18 projects or medical profiles. But yes good enough for your average company website or local sport club.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Membership uses standard .NET hashing algorithms from [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace. I thinks that's enough for many web solutions.